# How to use set or hashset

Tags: java, set, hashset

I have a situation where I have to create a Company with employees and every employee is into a Department. After that I must display every employees from every Department. ex if emp1 is in "Economy" department, emp2 is in "Economy", and emp3 is in "Management" . I need to display Economy Department : emp1 emp2, and Management Department : emp3 .

First time I create a array with departments .

```
String[] deps = {"Economy", "Management"};
ArrayList<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>();

emp1 = new Employee("fistname","lastname",deps[1]);
//deps[1] - "Management"

for(Employee e : emps){
     if(e.getDepartment() == deps[1]){
        System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

And this is not working. And someone told me that I have to use Set or HashSet for departments array.

Comment: 1. define "not working". 2. don't use `==` to compare strings.

Comment: And what exactly is a problem?

Comment: its not like if someone says you to use something you will have to use it. you should determine based on your requirement. also you have not posted any error and you can use any collection for that matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use Set but it's a possibility.
If you want your code to display the way you suggested, you might try that:

```
String[] deps = {"Economy", "Management"};
ArrayList<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>();

emp1 = new Employee("fistname","lastname",deps[1]);
//deps[1] - "Management"

for (int i = 0; i < deps.length; i++){
  System.out.println(deps[i] + " departement:");
  int count = 0;
  for(Employee e : emps){
     if(e.getDepartment().equals(deps[i])){
        System.out.println(e);
        count++;
     }
  }
  System.println(count + " employes in this department");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working . But if I want to count employee from every departament how I can do ? I tried with a count++ inside 'if' but display for example : Economy : emp1 emp2 , 2employees; Management : emp3 emp4 emp5, 5employees;  And I want : Economy : emp1 emp2 ,2 employees ; Management : emp3 emp4 emp5 , 3 employees.

Comment: I edited my code to implement a counting system. You have to remember to reinitialize the count when you switch department

Answer (score 0):

we can use map and linkedHashSet to perform these kind of operations
inside map use linkedHashSet